# Almost everywhere convergence of some series

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Let $\{r_n\}$ be an arbitrary numerical sequence. Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n\sqrt{|x-r_n|}}$. Prove that it converges almost everywhere on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: The complex-analysis tag seems not appropriate here.

Comment: Yeah! I think you are right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: For any $a$ and $r$, we have

$$\int_{a-1}^{a+1} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\lvert x-r\rvert}} \leqslant 2 \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}} = 4.$$

Comment: Good hint! Thanks